# How to cancel all threads after 5 seconds from the main thread with shared memory (shared variable)?

Tags: java, multithreading

My code:

```
public class Task3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    
    ExecutorService poolOfThreads = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        int finalI = i;
        poolOfThreads.submit(new Task2Thread(i, start));
    }

    poolOfThreads.shutdown();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    poolOfThreads.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
}
}


public class Task3Thread implements Runnable{
    
volatile boolean running = true;
private int id;
private long time;

public Task3Thread(int id, long time) {
    this.id = id;
    this.time = time;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Thread: " + id + ", time: " + (end - time));
    }
}

public void setRunning(boolean running) {
    this.running = running;
}
}
```

These classes spawn 10 threads, each of which every second prints to the console its number and the time elapsed since its launch in milliseconds.

Now I need to cancel all threads after 5 seconds from the main thread with shared memory (shared variable).

How to do it? Tell me please

Comment: You need to use `poolOfThreads.shutdownNow()` to cancel the tasks and send an interruption signal. Or you can cancel each future one by one. Or you can set the running variable to false, but you don't really need it.

Comment: In your case (when you have a blocking op - sleep()) you better just call thread's interrupt() method and make a break from the loop by InterruptedException. In this case sleep() will be interrupted immediately. If you just set running to false, you will not interrupt the blocking operation. while(running) pattern works not really well in the most cases.Even if you don't have a blocking operation, it's better to check while(!isInterrupted()) instead, since interruption is the standard way to stop/interrupt thread execution.For blocking IO the best way is to close channel/socket/etc

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this - store the thread references in an array and after 5 seconds you can fetch the threads one by one from the array and set the running volatile flag to false.
Please check the below modified main method:

Modified code:

public class Task3 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    int threadPoolSize = 10;

    Task3Thread[] threads = new Task3Thread[threadPoolSize];

    ExecutorService poolOfThreads = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        int finalI = i;
        Task3Thread task3Thread = new Task3Thread(i, start);
        threads[i-1] = task3Thread;
        poolOfThreads.submit(task3Thread);
    }


    poolOfThreads.shutdown();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    for (Task3Thread thread : threads)
    {
        thread.setRunning(false);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it is kind of irritating, how you use i in your for loop. One should always avoid deviations from common ways(normally i starts with 0),if not strictly necessary, since it distracts the reader from the important parts of the code. And what is the purpose of finalI?

Comment: I have copied the code from the author with three to four lines added to the answer. To your question of why i starts with i guess the author wants to number the thread id starting with 1 and not 0. You should read the entire post from start to end and not just randomly comment on some answers !!!

Comment: Sorry Melroy, I misplaced my comment - it belonged to the original post. No need to get berserk..